# How to display association rules using wordcloud in R?

Tags: r, word-cloud, arules

I was trying to display the frequent association rules with tag cloud in R.

I have the association rules sorted in desc order and exported the results to a csv file with each rule in the first column. However, after I imported the csv file and tried to form a wordcloud, I got an error message:   " Error in input$supoort : $ operator not defined for this S4 class"

I don't know what this means and how to get the wordcloud of frequent association rules, if possible.

Below is my code:

```
myData = read.transactions("data.csv", format = "basket",sep= ",", cols = 1, skip = 1)    
rules <- apriori(myData, parameter = list(supp = 0.010, conf = 0.5, minlen = 2))
rules_supp <- sort(rules, by = "support", descreasing = TRUE)
inspect(rules_supp)
write(rules_supp,file = "rules_supp.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
word <- read.csv(file = "rules_supp.csv") 
wordcloud(words = word$rules, freq = word$support)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `wordcloud(labels(rules))`. However, `wordcloud()` will break the rule labels into words, and I am not sure that this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is wordcloud package you can use to make a word cloud graphics but there is a better way to display association rules in R.

You can use the R package arulesViz that you find here : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesViz/vignettes/arulesViz.pdf

I have been using it for my paper I've published here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12652-017-0665-3

It helps you visualize the rules as correlation matrix or as a graph with nodes and oriented edges. Here are some of the graphics you can make.

[image: correlation matrix for association rules]